# Office.js throws GeneralException exception when tried to insertContentControl at the selection

Tags: office-js

I am developing a plugin for ms word using office.js,but i get the error when try to call `range.insertContentConrol()` like this [link](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) at the range witch is the word document selection range.This is my code:

```
function insertContentControl(outPutText) {
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) { 
        //context.document.body.insertText("test", "");
        // Create a proxy range object for the current selection. 
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        // Queue a commmand to create the content control.
        var myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
        myContentControl.tag = outPutText;
        myContentControl.title = 'test';
        //myContentControl.style = 'Heading 2';
        myContentControl.insertText(outPutText, 'replace');
        myContentControl.cannotEdit = true;
        return context.sync(); 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            //console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
 }
```

and the outPutText value may be "[1]" witch is to get by other function returned.

Comment: could you be so kind to share your build number and platform you are experiencing this? thanks

Comment: Ok, the office-js build version is 16.0.6207.1000 and ms word 2016 version is 1611（internal version 7571.2109） for windows

Comment: That's quite an old build, it would be great if you can update to latest and try this there.

Comment: Thanks.I is OK, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. I just tried your code in the build you mentioned, btw its not old its the latest publicly available build i was confused on the office-js build you sent.  The code runs ok. Can you please confirm that there is no issue? or if you are still experiencing the issue? if so please let me know what Office.js location you are using, it should be pointing to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

Comment: I download a sample from officedev github.It can not run success when  i try to use the office.js which build number is 16.0.6207.1000 contained sample package.I am using the office.js[link](  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js)  and it is ok.Thanks

Comment: Ok so when you use the office.js from our CDN your code works well. Good! Yes you should always use the office.js from CDN in fact samples should not include a, in this case stale, copy of office.js.  Can you please provide me a link to the sample ? I think we need to fix that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some discussion, the problem was that a stale copy from office.js was used (when downloading a sample ). The solution is to always get office.js from our CDN. (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js)